# How to execute same query with different bindings within same transaction in Rust SQLx?

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I need to insert multiple rows into a table, so I've got a query like `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?)` and arguments as list of pairs. Is there a way to execute it in SQLx without constructing a new string like `INSERT ... VALUES ((?, ?), ..., (?, ?))` each time?

I found [Query::execute_many](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/query/struct.Query.html#method.execute_many), but I'm not sure if it's doing what, say, Python's [executemany()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) from mysql adaptor is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually MySql Python Connector's `execute_many` constructs `VALUES ((?, ?), ..., (?, ?))` internally. If you want do that in `sqlx`, [`QueryBuilder::push_values`](https://docs.rs/sqlx-core/0.5.13/sqlx_core/query_builder/struct.QueryBuilder.html#method.push_values) can construct SQL `VALUES` strings for you.